# Call a already generated C code from java

Tags: java, c

Is it possible to call the C code (which has been generated py Beremiz Editor) from java?
I dont want to edit the generated C code i just want to call it from my Java program.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to turn your C code into a DLL or so and use JNI.  It'd be better if you were using C++ as "a better C" - use a C++ compiler to create that shared library.

Comment: you can write a make file and create an executable ( static library ) for your c code , and then call it from java program.

Comment: I am using JNI first time could you please little bit explain more step by step. I have JNI tutorials but in that they are writing both C and Java. In my case i dont have to write the C code it would be generated by the Beremiz editor.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the generated code, you can write a bridge in C that would accept calls from Java and forward them to your generated code. It can be compiled together with the generated code, making the single .dll or .so library.

JNI interface has many specific requirements and agreements. It cannot be used to call the arbitrary C function that was written without having JNI in mind.

This is a very common task when integrating existing C libraries into Java framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JNI to do this, a good tutorial is available here:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html

This allows you to call your C code from in java.

Comment: I have JNI tutorials but in that they are writing both C and Java. In my case i dont have to write the C code it would be generated by the Beremiz editor. I just want to know how i can call that c code from java.

Comment: You would probably need to write some linking C code, based on the C code provided by JNI, which then calls your autogenerated C code, this is the same as how @h22 suggested